# Creating a sub-spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to a create a sub-spinner in android in the sense a nested spinner.My aim is that if one option is selected in the main spinner then as per the selected option the sub spinner options must be displayed.

In my project i am giving an option to select states in the main spinner.So as per the selected state i must be able to display the districts in the sub spinner.I have successfully implemented the main spinner but what should i do so as to display the districts(in sub spinner) based on the state selected.

region_slection.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

          <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp" />

          <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/spinner2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_x="0dp"
              android:layout_y="98dp" 
              android:entries="@array/states_array"/>

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn1"
              android:layout_width="106dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_x="100dp"
              android:layout_y="220dp"
              android:text="Submit" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Region_selection.java

```
    public class Region_selection extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner1,spinner2;
    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.region_selection);

        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    //get the selected dropdown list value
        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(Region_selection.this,
                            "OnClickListener : " + 
                            "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                            "\nSpinner 2 : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }
}
```

CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java

```
    public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    //private static final String TAG = null;
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDistrict;
        String state_selected;

        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:     //state spinner(parent spinner)
            Log.e(TAG, parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString());
            state_selected = parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString();

            if(state_selected.equals("Kerala"))
            {
                adapterDistrict = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.kerala_districts, R.layout.region_selection);
            }


            else
            {
                adapterDistrict = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, "Hai", R.layout.region_selection);
            }
            adapterDistrict.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.region_selection);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapterDistrict);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I am getting error for using TAG variable there and getting error for using createFromResource.The error says "The method createFromResource (context,int,int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (CustomOnItemListner,int, int).

I also dont know why i am getting an error for using findViewById in CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java.

Answer (score 0):

Override onItemSelected to achieve your requirement. 
The activity/class should implement OnItemSelectedListener.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCity; 
    String mCountrySelected;
      switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.create_sp_country:  // parent spinner id
            Log.e(TAG,parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString());
            mCountrySelected = parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString();

            if(mCountrySelected.equals("United Kingdom"))
            {
                adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.United_Kingdom_Cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            }
            else
            {
                adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.create_empty_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            }

            adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            createSpCity.setAdapter(adapterCity); // Where createSpCity is the child spinner
            break;

        }
}
```

Comment: so should i create 2 separate classes for main spinner and sub spinner  ?

Comment: Another  error is for using createFromResource.The error says "The method createFromResource (context,int,int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (CustomOnItemListner,int, int)... Where "CustomOnItemListner" is my class name @a.gomes

Comment: Hi Krishna, you do not need two classes for the spinners just implement onItemSelectedLister in your activity class.

Comment: 'Log.e(TAG,parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString())'; it is just for debugging purposes. You could replace TAG with a String constant to view the value in logcat.

Comment: at the third comment. This issue is because the activity context is not passed to the CustomOnItemListner class. To avoid all these issues just implement onItemSelected listener to you main activity and move the code from CustomOnItemListener. This will also solve the findViewById issue as it is a method of the activity class.

Comment: even though i did as u said i am getting an error on createFromResource within the else statement.

Comment: : can u plz show how to put that code in one class bcoz when i tried to do it i am having lot of error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweeVUiqmiuQalBNSjY0b0dCWFE/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweeVUiqmiuQWGRmQmNGcVdOakU/edit?usp=sharing

The varaible "qw" within the else statement is an integer constant that i have created.